# ImportError: No module named newbytes

Tags: python, logging, airflow, flash-message

Meet problem in `airflow` with `python2.7.10`

It seem that `hiveserver2.py` has wrong package path so that it can get the right path for `newbytes`.

But I have no idea about fixing this problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 859, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 472, in format
    if self.usesTime():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 456, in usesTime
    return self._fmt.find("%(asctime)") >= 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/future/types/__init__.py", line 145, in wrapper
    from .newbytes import newbytes
ImportError: No module named newbytes
Logged from file hiveserver2.py, line 292
```

line 292: hiveserver2.py

```
290 def close_operation(self):
291     if self._last_operation_active:
292         log.info('Closing active operation')
293         self._reset_state()
```

> Finally I fixed this problem by changing `impyla` version: from `0.16.0` to `0.13.8`.

Comment: Could you add the part that caused the problem in `hiverserver2.py`?

Comment: I updated the code in `hiveserver2.py`